# Noms pluriels se terminant par -i et admettant la variante -is

Tags: orthographe, pluriel, emprunts

Les mots suivants sont des noms masculins pluriels se terminant par *-i* mais ayant la particularité d'admettre la variante *-is* :

- « lapilli »
- « rœsti » ou « rösti »
- « zakouski »

Mais, les noms masculins pluriels suivants se terminant aussi par *-i* n'acceptent pas la variante *-is* :

- « arditi »
- « fontanili »
- « hastati »
- « lapsi »
- « macchiaioli »

Ma question est donc : qu'est-ce qui détermine si la variante *-is* est acceptée ou non ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Le pluriel régulier en `-s` (ou invariant pour les mots se terminant par `s`, `x` ou `z` au singulier) est toujours accepté pour les mots importés récemment. Souvent, l'import du pluriel est aussi accepté.

*Rösti* vient de l'allemand où son pluriel est aussi *Röstis*, il n'y a donc pas de variation possible.

*Arditi*, *fontanili*, *lapilli* et *macchiaoli* (comme *spaghetti*, *ravioli* et autres noms de pâtes) sont des emprunts d'un pluriel italien, utilisé au singulier comme au pluriel en français. On admet du coup soit le pluriel emprunté en `-i`, soit le pluriel régulier en `-is`.

*Zakouski* est aussi un import d'un pluriel (russe), et de même on peut écrire *zakouski* ou *zakouskis* au pluriel. De même pour *lapsi* (latin), dont l'orthographe *lapsis* au pluriel [est bien attestée](https://www.google.fr/search?q=%22des+lapsis%22&btnG=Chercher+des+livres&tbm=bks&tbo=1&hl=fr). *Hastati* est aussi un pluriel latin ; il est apparemment trop rare pour que Google Books trouve une occurrence du pluriel *hastati* mais ce pluriel est néanmoins correct.

L'affirmation selon laquelle *arditis*, *fontanilis*, etc. seraient incorrectes est fausse. Dans la mesure où ce sont des mots français (et non des citations d'un mot d'une autre langue, qui devraient être composées en italiques), ils admettent un pluriel français en `-s`. La [réforme de l'orthographe de 1990](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_fran%C3%A7ais_en_1990) a entériné le pluriel régulier comme préféré pour les emprunts. Ce n'est pas une nouveauté de la réforme : avant, les deux formes cohabitaient déjà ; la réforme a seulement déclaré le pluriel régulier comme officiellement valide et préféré.

Answer (score 4):

Les mots 'savants' tels que ceux cités sont très peu utilisés et gardent leur nature italienne, suisse ou russe.

En revanche, les mots courants issus d'un pluriel italien ne sont plus perçus comme tels et adoptent la grammaire française.

En particulier la plupart des dénominations de pâtes déjà au pluriel en italien prennent à peu près toujours un 's' en français, comme *spaghetti*, *ravioli*, *cannelloni*, *gnocchi* et autres macaronis (*maccheroni*).

Il en est de même pour *panini* et les *paparazzi*, même si le Larousse donne les deux terminaisons pour ce dernier.

Certains pluriels en 'e' comme *tagliatelle* et *lasagne* prennent eux-aussi toujours un 's' en français.

Answer (score 1):

*Arditi*, *hastati*, *fontanili* et *lapsi* proviennent de l'italien/latin, et donc le *i* représente déjà la marque du pluriel. Rajouter un *s* serait un peu redondant et dissonant.

Pour cette même raison il est curieux en effet que *lapillis* prenne un *s*. Je pense que cela vient du fait qu'il est nettement plus utilisé (notamment en cours de géologie des classes de collèges et/ou lycée français) que les autres mots que tu proposes, et donc il a du prendre la coloration francophone plus rapidement que les autres.

---

Pour *rösti* et *zakouski* je sèche, ne connaissant pas leur langue de provenance. Je laisserai le soin de leur explication à quelqu'un d'autre.

Comment: Merci pour le feedback.

Comment: *Rösti* est un mot germanique déjà au pluriel, écrit  sans "s" même [en français](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%B6sti), par contre A.Rey signale qu'il peut être masculin ou féminin. *Rösti* vient du français rôtir (les *rösti* sont des galettes de purée de pommes de terre rissolées). *Zakouski* est un mot russe déjà au pluriel, singulier *zakouska*. En français, sauf à frimer, on dit *un zakousti*, et non pas *un zakouska*. Pour *lapilli* les deux pluriels sont admis (A. Rey), italien et francisé, même si le [TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie/lapilli) ne donne que le pluriel italien.

Comment: *Lapilli* peut prendre un `s` au pluriel tout simplement parce que c'est comme ça qu'on forme un pluriel en français. Les exceptions ne concernent que des mots anciens, pas les emprunts plus récents.